# If statements on Update method

Tags: unity

[image]

I want to disable axe collider when e is pressed and enable it again when e is pressed again. I have the bool "axeOnHand" so If statements can be called when needed. But when i press e, both If statements are called. I think the problem is they are called in the same frame. But i don't know how to solve this issue.

Comment: And please don't post code as a screenshot, there is a code markup for this. It makes it hard to debug your code (though in this case simply reading to find the issue is enough)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

both called because you set `axeonhand=false` therefore second `if` statement evaluate to `true`. change second `if` to `else if`.

Answer (score 0):

Your first if-statement sets `axeOnHand = true`, so when the code execution reaches the second if-statement, that variable will have a different value than it had before.

I would structure the code like this:

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown("e") {
    if (axeOnHand) {
          axeOnHand = false;
          // toggle axe collider
    } else {
          if (axeCollided) {
              // toggle axe collider
              axeOnHand = true;
              pickUpAxe();
          }
    }
}
```

I omitted a couple lines. I would have included all the lines of your code if I had been able to copy&paste. Which I would have been able to do if you had included your code in text form instead of as a screenshot.

Comment: thank you, it works